# Non-Nil User Crashing When Unwrapped - Firebase, SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, swift5

Unwrapping values the conventional way in SwiftUI views is not allowed, but you can do so within the `body` of, say, an `HStack` or a `VStack`. Below I am trying to unwrap a user I was certain was not nil. My `LoginView` lets a user create an account on Firebase Firestore, logs you in if a user enters the correct values, and shows an alert view if not.

In my `HomeView.swift`, the first screen after launch, I crash when trying to present the user image. However, when I unwrap the user, the user is still nil in the console. I think this is because Firebase doesn't have time to load the image before the view initializes. But I could be wrong. Help.

```
struct HomeProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @State var showDashboard = false
    var user: User?
    
    var body: some View {
        if user != nil {
            URLImage(URL(string: user!.profileImageUrl)!, content: {
                $0.image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            })
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.9490196078, blue: 0.9490196078, alpha: 1)))
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showDashboard) {
                DashboardView(showDashboard: $showDashboard)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think I need an optional user, here, but I do not know how to safely unwrap the user otherwise. Another version is using the session `EnvironmentObject` to access the currently logged user.

```
struct HomeProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @State var showDashboard = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if session.isLoggedIn {
            URLImage(URL(string: session.userSession!.profileImageUrl)!, content: {
                $0.image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            })
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.9490196078, blue: 0.9490196078, alpha: 1)))
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showDashboard) {
                DashboardView(showDashboard: $showDashboard)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `session` property belongs to a `SessionStore` class and is essentially an optional `User`.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.isLoggedIn, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
        }
    }

    var userSession: User?
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    func listenAuthenticationState() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                print(user.email as Any)
                let firestoreUserId = Ref.FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: user.uid)
                firestoreUserId.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let dict = document?.data() {
                        guard let decodeUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else { return }
                        self.userSession = decodeUser
                    }
                }
                self.isLoggedIn = true
            } else {
                print("User is Logged Out")
                self.isLoggedIn = false
                self.userSession = nil
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The logged in user is indeed logged in but I cannot access any properties.

Answer (score 0):

Set isLoggedIn exactly at the place you set userSession, because it is done in async callback, and do this on main queue (to update UI properly)

```
firestoreUserId.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let dict = document?.data() {
        guard let decodeUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.userSession = decodeUser
           self.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my `session.userSession` is still nil and I am still crashing. Good call on the `Dispatch.main.async`, though

Comment: the error is occurring on my profileImageUrl, viz; `session.userSession.profileImageUrl`

Answer (score 0):

I have this working. Not sure how scalable it is but I am doing a not equals nil. I also put it in a button to toggle it versus an `onTapGesture`.

```
struct HomeProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @State var showDashboard = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if session.isLoggedIn {
            if (session.userSession?.profileImageUrl) != nil {
                Button(action: { self.showDashboard.toggle() } ) {
                    URLImage(URL(string: session.userSession!.profileImageUrl)!, content: {
                        $0.image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    })
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.9490196078, blue: 0.9490196078, alpha: 1)))
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showDashboard) {
                        DashboardView(showDashboard: $showDashboard)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```